# JavaScript parse HTML tags get text translate and put translated text back in tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a task to extract text from HTML tags, translate it and put the translated text back to its tag. The HTML structure is dynamic

For example HTML

```
<span style='font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;font-weight:0;font-style:normal;color:#000000'>katze</span>
```

I need to extract katze, ok

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var regex = /(&nbsp;|<([^>]+)>)/ig;
var body = "<span style='font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;font-weight:0;font-style:normal;color:#000000'>katze</span>";
var result = body.replace(regex, "");
alert(result);

</script>
```

Result : katze

then via API it is translated and result is cat

I have to put it back in HTML like this

```
<span style='font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;font-weight:0;font-style:normal;color:#000000'>cat</span>
```

I have no idea how to do it, it has to be on clear JS, no jQuery no nothing

And HTML can have other than span tags, like this:

```
<p> style='font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;font-weight:0;font-style:normal;color:#000000'Bullet points:</p>
<ul>
    <li style='font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;font-weight:0;font-style:normal;color:#000000'>point 1</li>
    <li style='font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;font-weight:0;font-style:normal;color:#000000'>point 2</li>
</ul>
```

or like this:

```
<span style='font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;font-weight:0;font-style:normal;color:#000000'><strong>katze</strong></span>
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE] and more testcase

Comment: problem that I am 0 in JS

Comment: Time to start learning JS :D

Comment: I am python back, I don 't need this at all but at work don't ask this

Answer (score 0):

You should start by learning how to [manipulate the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents). If I get your problem, you should be able to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). I dont know how do you plan to do the translation part. If you have no clue, read the Google Translation API.

```js
function translateToFrench() {
  return "chat"
}

const deutschCat = document.querySelector("span").textContent;
document.querySelector("span").textContent = translateToFrench(deutschCat)
```

```html
<span style='font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;font-weight:0;font-style:normal;color:red'>katze</span>
```

Comment: Translation part is not important here

Comment: well it can be not only span tag, where the text is